# Continuous curve on a Hilbert Space where any three points form a right angled triangle

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Give an example of a continuous curve $\gamma$ in the Hilbert space (i.e., an image of a continuous map $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow H)$ with the following “miraculous” property: for every three points $A,B, C\in \gamma$, the triangle ABC is right-angled.

This is a homework problem. I am not asking for a solution. But I am just requesting if you can point me to a direction in which I should proceed. Because I am quite clueless how such a curve is possible in an Euclidean space.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the Hilbert space" you mentioned in your text - so is the Hilbert space in your question fixed or can it be chosen fittingly? Also you might want to rule out the trivial solution $\phi:[0,1]\to H$, $x\mapsto 0$ (which obviously satisfies $\langle \phi(r)-\phi(s),\phi(s)-\phi(t)\rangle=0$ for all $r,s,t\in[0,1]$)

Comment: I think here the Hilbert space refers to the $L_2[0,1]$ function space with the L_2 norm.

Comment: A solution seems to be provided here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317762. However, I do not have access to this article.

Comment: Yes, @grew The paper has a solution though but Its far more general than I needed. I have a solution form the professor should with the Fourier basis of $L_2[0,1]$, should I post it?